# I can't display posts only with a boolean field set to true in my template

Tags: python, html, django, wagtail

In short - I have a bootstrap carousel and it works nicely, however I can't get it to display only fields with 'featured' set to 'true'

I have tried doing `for post in posts.objects.featured` (the carousel literally does not show up at all then) and variations like `posts.objects.filter(featured=True)` (it says it can't parse the remainder).

Here's the code from the template where I am trying to display the carousel image only with items with featured=True

```
{% for post in posts.objects.featured %}
  <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %} ">
  {% image post.image fill-1920x500 %}
   <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
      <h2 id="inner-carousel-title">{{post.title}}</h2>
      <h4><a href="{% pageurl post %}" style="color:white;text-shadow:2px 2px 4px #000000" >something</a></h4>
   </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Again, I just want the carousel to show up only with featured posts
As a side note- it'd be awesome if it only showed 3 posts.

EDIT - Here's my model.py for the page

```
    class BlogPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
        description = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True)

        content_panels = Page.content_panels + \
            [FieldPanel("description", classname="full")]

        def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            context = super(BlogPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
            context['posts'] = self.posts
            context['blog_page'] = self
            return context
```

Comment: Try writing only posts.featured

Comment: Where is `self.posts` defined? I suspect the problem is that this is giving you a queryset of plain `Page` instances rather that the specific page model that the `featured` flag is defined on - as a result, filtering by that flag won't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do this in the template do:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.featured %}
        <div> ... <div/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

But you can also pass only the featured posts to your template in your view. Just add:

```
...
featured_posts = Post.objects.filter(featured=True)[:4]
return render('post_list.html', {'featured_posts': featured_posts, ...})
```

If you’re using Django’s generic `ListView` and you’re only showing the featured posts, you can set the `queryset` property to filter only the featured posts. If you’re also showing the other posts in your ListView, add the featured_posts to your context by overriding `get_context_data()`.

Comment: So where do I do that featured_posts? models.py?

Comment: I said: in your view. I don’t know how you built your view (function view or CBV) so I just suggest ways you could approach it. It depends on your view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if the way I suggested in the comment doesn't work

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if post.featured %}
        // write down your stuff
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```